# How do I get a value from Postgres, in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm now trying to build the user authentication logic of a website. Now I should check, when a user tries to log in, does he have a registered email/password already. But I cannot just simply get the field's value from the DB, as a string.

In the database, I have 6 fields (`isSuperuser`, `fullName`, `institution`, `password`, `email`, `approved`). For the authentication, the unfinished method is here:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next)=> {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const data = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email= $1;`, [email])
  const arr = data.rows
  //const arr = data.rows;
  .then(user=> {
    if(arr==null || arr== undefined || arr.length==0){
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Login authentication failed!"
      })
    }

  })
})
```

My problem is, that, when I check, if the email, provided at login, already exists, I should simply compare it (`req.body.email`) with the value(s) of the `email` field in the database. But I did not find any solution, how to just get a string, as a result for the query. The `const arr` gives an array, from which I cannot get the value of the `email` key. So far, this code might works (though ugly as hell), but when it comes to password compare, I will bleed.

If I try
`client.query("SELECT password FROM user_table WHERE email= $1;", [email])`
it only gives back an empty array.

What do I do wrong? Any solution, please?

Comment: If it gives an empty array then you dont have given email in your db it means you can simply return a message with "Email doesn't exists"

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure about PostgreSql but I know sql so give it a try;

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const data = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email= ${email}`).then((result) => {
        return result
    })
    if (!data) { // OR if data is an array then use "data.length == 0"
        return res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Login authentication failed!"
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes thank you, it makes it look nicer, but still I should somehow reach an EXACT value of a field. The best would be to put the value of field "email", where for example fullName="Jack Brown" into a variable.

Comment: ok so i just now read your updated question. so your problem is to get result as a string right ? Also, can you please ADD sample result now

Comment: Exactly. Meanwhile, I tried, what you wrote, in a completely seperated method, and data returns a complex object, with rows, fields, parsers etc objects as values. I just want to do a query, like (`SELECT password FROM user_table WHERE email= $1;` , email) (where the value of email comes from req.body.email), and to get that 'password' 's value as a string.

Comment: Oh, is your password is hashed before saving to DB?

Comment: Please add sample data then only we can develop something

Comment: here is the complete project: https://github.com/nabsabt/object-upload, the mentioned code is in object-upload/backend/routes/. The db i'm working from is local, but the data are very simple. "fullName" values are like 'nagy bence', 'kiss antal', 'tamara', "email" values are for ex. 'nagyb@szikm.hu', 'kissa@gmail.com', and yes, password is hashed. I'm not sure if I gave enough info with that (values are in hungarian, as I have to publish this for a hungarian co.)

Comment: You want to retrieve the password from db or want to dehash the retrieved password to string ?

Comment: I resolved it, by simply querying the data (email, in this case) from db like this:
user.rows[0]["email"]
where 'user' is the result of the query. I could simply compare this with the req.body.email.